# gae ndb query multiple values

Tags: database

I am using python on GAE.
I have a query where I need to match a field against value coming form a list. 
My entity looks like:

```
 class TimeTableChange(ndb.Model):
    """A Change entry.""" 
        details = ndb.StringProperty()
        class_label = ndb.StringProperty()
        class_id = ndb.IntegerProperty()
        year = ndb.IntegerProperty()
        month = ndb.IntegerProperty()
        day_of_month = ndb.IntegerProperty()
        hour = ndb.IntegerProperty()
        type = ndb.StringProperty()
        ts = ndb.IntegerProperty()
```

I would like to run a query that looks like (**MySQL like example**):

```
select * from TimeTableChange 
where year = 2017 and month = 8 and day_of_month = 12 and class_id IN [12,34,67]
```

The list [12,34,67] is just an example.The list may be empty or contain N integers. How do I create the proper ndb query?
For the year / month / day_of_month I use

```
query = query.filter(ndb.AND(TimeTableChange.year == tomorrow.year,
                                     TimeTableChange.month == tomorrow.month,
                                     TimeTableChange.day_of_month == tomorrow.day))
```

and it works fine. Now I need to match 'class_id' against a list

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
query = query.filter(ndb.AND(ndb.AND(TimeTableChange.year == tomorrow.year,
                                     TimeTableChange.month == tomorrow.month,
                                     TimeTableChange.day_of_month == tomorrow.day), TimeTableChange.class_id.IN([12, 34, 67])))
```

Comment: what about the int list? How it is represented in the query?

Comment: I updated the answer and i think this will work for int.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use DateTime property.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/entity-property-reference#Date_and_Time

```
class TimeTableChange(ndb.Model):
    created_at = ndb.DateTimeProperty()

from datetime import datetime
dateobj = datetime.strptime('Aug 12 2017  1:33PM', '%b %d %Y %I:%M%p')
query = TimeTableChange.query(TimeTableChange.created_at >= dateobj)
```

It uses the default Python datetime format. Much faster queries that support other datetime operations than several ANDs or filters.